# Reshape 2d into 3d matrix with rows as columns and columns as the 3rd dimension

Tags: r

How would I reshape a matrix where I'd need every 2 rows to start a new column and every column to be in the third dimension in R? I haven't really tried anything outside of `dim()` which obviously didn't work, as I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this transformation.

What I have:

```
d h
c g
b f
a e
```

What I want:

```
[ , , 1]
b d
a c

[ , , 2]
g h
e f
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the required structure of your matrix adjusting the `dim` attribute.

I added two additional rows to your matrix, it looks like this :

```
mat <- structure(c("d", "c", "b", "a", "k", "l", "h", "g", "f", "e", 
"j", "m"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))
mat

#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "d"  "h" 
#[2,] "c"  "g" 
#[3,] "b"  "f" 
#[4,] "a"  "e" 
#[5,] "k"  "j" 
#[6,] "l"  "m"
```

To get every column into 3rd dimension and only 2 values in each column you can do :

```
dim(mat) <- c(2, nrow(mat)/2, ncol(mat))
mat

#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "d"  "b"  "k" 
#[2,] "c"  "a"  "l" 

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "h"  "f"  "j" 
#[2,] "g"  "e"  "m"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `array`

```
 array(t(df1), c(2, 2, 2))
```